# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int16' to type 'System.String' - AsEnumerable().ToDictionary

Tags: c#, linq, casting

```
Dictionary<string, DataRow> dtUsers;
using (DataSet dsmyTable = DbConnection.db_Select_Query
                     ("use myDb select * from myTable"))
{
    dtUsers= dsmyTable .Tables[0].AsEnumerable().
         ToDictionary(row => row.Field<string>("UserId"));
}
```

Alright UserId is a `smallint` column
But I want to cast it as string.

How should I modify the above linq ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't cast an `int` to a string, but you can get the string representation of the int:

```
dtUsers= dsmyTable .Tables[0].AsEnumerable().
         ToDictionary(row => row.Field<short>("UserId").ToString());
```

However, you should only do this for display purposes. In general, you'll want to keep the int for as long as you can, as it is much easier to deal with an int instead of parsing it from a string everywhere.

Comment: thanks for answer. so you are saying it is impossible i can cast int to string at this linq expression ?

Comment: Yes, simply because there is no cast from `short` to `string`. What should it be? If you have the `short` `1234`, what should be the resulting string from it?

Comment: i already find the solution. this is working dtUsers= dsmyTable .Tables[0].AsEnumerable(). ToDictionary(row => row.Field<Int16>("UserId").ToString());

Comment: Which is exactly my answer, as `short` is equivalent to `System.Int16`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `ToString()` method. Of course, this is just for presentation for your `smallint` column.

```
dtUsers= dsmyTable .Tables[0].AsEnumerable().
         ToDictionary(row => row.Field<short>("UserId").ToString());
```

Comment: It doesn't gave any error in my editor. What is your error code?

Comment: ok i found the solution :d dtUsers= dsmyTable .Tables[0].AsEnumerable().
         ToDictionary(row => row.Field<Int16>("UserId").ToString());

Comment: It's because you are trying to access a `short` as a `string`, which just isn't possible. See my answer for the correct way.